# How to run a react+django app as an Ubuntu service?

Tags: reactjs, django, ubuntu

I know I can run a React + Django app from the command line, e.g.:

```
> npm start
> python manage.py runserver
```

and stop it with Ctrl+C. But I want it to keep running even after I exit the terminal or reboot the computer, and I also want to be able to stop it easily, just like the other services on my Ubuntu machine. Is there a simple way to run the app by e.g.

```
> service react start
> service django start
```

and stop it using

```
> service react stop
> service django stop
```

so that the service automatically starts at startup?